# Windows 10 does not detect my wireless mouse after a few hours of usage

Tags: windows, windows-10, mouse, wireless-mouse

I have bought a Logitech M238 wireless mouse and it worked prefectly for a while, but after a couple of days it started to randomly disconnect. I solved this problem by plugging into another USB port but that didn't last too much. I have tried a different mouse and it worked perfectly and plugging the mouse to another computer which was also fine. I have no idea what could be wrong.
I use a Lenovo laptop with preinstalled Windows 10, guess that could be the problem.

It would be great to solve this problem without reinstalling windows, thanks for any help.

Comment: The usb dongle may be failing...

Comment: It works perfectly fine in my other laptop

Answer (score 0):

There should be some reason this happened.

1. The connection of the USB Port with the USB Wireless have a problem (Less likely since switching also caused issue)

> This can be checked / confirmed by getting USB malfunction errors, or the connecting and disconnecting sound of USB being plug/unplugged.

Try pushing in the USB, or get it into certain position.
Getting a new USB port would be good.

2. Windows has problem with the USB Wireless (this is also very less likely)

> Try checking the drivers are correctly installed.

3. Your Wireless mouse battery started to wear off (more likely)

> Try changing the battery

4. Instead of the mouse dying, the platform it is on isn't flat.

> Try using the mouse on a flat surface, like books (color should NOT be red, or plastic cover), or mouse pad.

If your BIOS is UEFI BIOS with mouse compatibility, try playing around, checking if the mouse died or not, to confirm that the error is caused by Windows 10, BUT DO NOT CHANGE ANY SETTINGS.